# Pseudo-code of a recursive descent parser

Tags: parsing, recursive-descent

We got this context-free grammar that looks relatively simple and we are required to write a pseudo code of a recursive descent parser for that CFG.
We need to use getToken()/nextToken() and unreadToken(Token) procedures.
I have never done anything like that before and have tried finding examples online but none of them have helped me.
The CFG is:

S → xSyS
S → ySxS
S → ε

Comment: What is the parser supposed to return? Just a boolean status or a full parse tree?

Comment: Also, this grammar looks highly ambiguous. How is the parser supposed to deal with that? Return all possible parses?

Comment: It is supposed to return nothing but prints an error